# How to filter results in forEach loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am having a hard time figuring out how to iterate over an array and only doing something when a specific value is found.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

What I have in mind:

```
ForEach Entry, Where X = Y {
 console.log('I did something');
}
```

Actual Data:

```
[{
    "id" : 0,
    "fullName" : "George",
    "email": "george@test.ca",
    "group": 'Faculty',
    "totalFiles": 12,
    "outstandingFiles": 10,

},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "fullName" : "Albert",
    "email": "albert@test.ca",
    "group": 'Student',
    "totalFiles": 15,
    "outstandingFiles": 8,
}];
```

Comment: what do you want to filter?

Comment: I would like to filter for where Group = 'Faculty' for example

Comment: `arr.filter(o => o.group === "Faculty").forEach(o => console.log(o))`

Comment: Thanks Rock Star

Comment: To the community => Why the downvotes? Legitimate question from a new developer, why the negs?

Comment: Probably because this question has been asked and answered countless times.

Comment: Fair enough. All I could find in the search is php related. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many options to filter value without foreach, you can use find which will return the first matching value

```js
var myArray = [{
    "id" : 0,
    "fullName" : "George",
    "email": "george@test.ca",
    "group": 'Faculty',
    "totalFiles": 12,
    "outstandingFiles": 10,

},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "fullName" : "Albert",
    "email": "albert@test.ca",
    "group": 'Student',
    "totalFiles": 15,
    "outstandingFiles": 8,
}];

var result = myArray.find(t=>t.group =='Faculty');
console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**

```js
var myArray = [{
    "id" : 0,
    "fullName" : "George",
    "email": "george@test.ca",
    "group": 'Faculty',
    "totalFiles": 12,
    "outstandingFiles": 10,

},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "fullName" : "Albert",
    "email": "albert@test.ca",
    "group": 'Student',
    "totalFiles": 15,
    "outstandingFiles": 8,
}];

 myArray.filter(t=>t.group =='Faculty').forEach(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear, I need to do a forEach with the results afterwards. Using this I filter first, then do the forEach with the new result variable?

Comment: did the answer help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you want many results or [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if you want the first result to your query

This is an example using filter

```
const data = [
    {
        "id" : 0,
        "fullName" : "George",
        "email": "george@test.ca",
        "group": 'Faculty',
        "totalFiles": 12,
        "outstandingFiles": 10,
    },{
        "id" : 1,
        "fullName" : "Albert",
        "email": "albert@test.ca",
        "group": 'Student',
        "totalFiles": 15,
        "outstandingFiles": 8,
    }
];

const result = data.filter(info => {
    return info.group === 'Faculty'
})
```

`console.log(result)` will output

```
[ { id: 0,
    fullName: 'George',
    email: 'george@test.ca',
    group: 'Faculty',
    totalFiles: 12,
    outstandingFiles: 10 } ]
```

You can learn about this and more array methods in http://javascript.info/array-methods